# unable to get collection names with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

This Ruby code prints the collection names inside `"db"`. Trying to do the same with coffee

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo
mongocl = MongoClient.new("localhost")
p mongocl["db"].collection_names
mongocl.close
```

Equivalent coffeescript code(not sure).

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
mongoose.connect 'localhost/db'
mongoose.connection.on 'open', (err) ->
  mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames (err, data) ->
    console.log data
    return 
mongoose.connection.close()
```

Could someone point out the bug in this?
I'm using the latest mongoose@3.8.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing the connection before the `open` event handler has the chance to execute.

Move the `close()` call inside the callback passed to `collectionNames`:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
mongoose.connect 'localhost/db'
mongoose.connection.on 'open', (err) ->
  mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames (err, data) ->
    console.log data
    mongoose.connection.close()
```